# Map<String, List<? extends Object>> filtering issue with Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have `Employee` object that has `3` fields: `name`, `role`, `companyName`.

I need to filter `Employee` objects based on a `role` property.

Despite that I'm applying `filter` in the stream in the code below, it's returning the **entire** data.

*My code:*

```
public static Map<String, List<? extends Employee>> testMappingFilter(List<Employee> emp) {
    Map<String, List<? extends Employee>> dataInput = new HashMap<>();
    for (Employee entry : emp) {
        dataInput.put("senior", new ArrayList(emp));
        dataInput.put("junior", new ArrayList(emp));
    }
    
    Map<String, List<? extends Employee>> dataResponse = new HashMap<>();
    
    Set<String> realmroles = new HashSet<>();
    realmroles.add("admin");
    realmroles.add("user");
    
    Either<Map<String, List<? extends Employee>>, ResponseFormat> followedResourcesServices = Either.left(dataInput);
    
    realmroles.stream().forEach(role -> 
        followedResourcesServices.left().value().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(elements -> elements.getValue().stream().anyMatch(i -> ((Employee) i).getRole().contains(role)))
            .forEach(elements -> dataResponse.put(elements.getKey(), elements.getValue())));
    
    return dataResponse;
}
```

***Sample data:***

*Expected Output:*

(expected roles are only `"admin"` and `"user"`, data related to role `"super"` should not come)

```json
{ “senior” :
   [ { ”name”:”ABC”, “role”:”admin”, “companyName”:”ABC &Co” },
     { ”name”:”XYZ”, “role”:”admin”, “companyName”:”XYZ &Co” },
     { ”name”:”RST”, “role”:”user”, “companyName”:”RST &Co” } ],
  “junior” :
   [ { ”name”:”ABC”, “role”:”admin”, “companyName”:”ABC &Co” },
     { ”name”:”XYZ”, “role”:”admin”, “companyName”:”XYZ &Co” },
     { ”name”:”RST”, “role”:”user”, “companyName”:”RST &Co” } ] 
}
```

*Actual output:*

```json
{ “senior” :
   [ { ”name”:”ABC”, “role”:”admin”, “companyName”:”ABC &Co” },
     { ”name”:”DDD”, “role”:”super”, “companyName”:”DDD &Co” },
     { ”name”:”XYZ”, “role”:”admin”, “companyName”:”XYZ &Co” },
     { ”name”:”RST”, “role”:”user”, “companyName”:”RST &Co” } ],
  “junior” :
   [ { ”name”:”ABC”, “role”:”admin”, “companyName”:”ABC &Co” },
     { ”name”:”DDD”, “role”:”super”, “companyName”:”DDD &Co” },
     { ”name”:”XYZ”, “role”:”admin”, “companyName”:”XYZ &Co” },
     { ”name”:”RST”, “role”:”user”, “companyName”:”RST &Co” } ] 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code:

- The filtering logic is incorrect: you said you need to retain only roles `"admin"` and `"user"`, but according to your code any `List` of `Employee` that contains at least one employee with either of these roles is good to go (meaning the **whole** list, not only employee having the required role). That's why you see roles `”super”` in your output. You need to filter the *employees* in each *list*, instead of filtering the *lists*.
- That's not a job for `Stream.forEach`, which operates via *side-effects*. It's **discouraged** to be used in place of [*reduction operations*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction). Have a look at the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects), especially pay attention to the code examples.
- Instead of iterating over the `Set` of roles, we can simply use `contains()` check, and iterate only over the entries of the map which you're retrieving by calling `Either.left(dataInput).value()`.

To accumulate the values from the stream we have a wide range of operations, and the most suitable of them in this case is `collect()`, because we need to perform mutable reduction.

In this case we can't apply the filtering logic inside the stream without creating new objects (*which costs performance*), or without mutating the existing data (*even if you no longer need it, it's not the way to go because mutating the objects in the stream goes against the Functional programming paradigm*).

Another option we have is to perform filtering inside a `Collector` while accumulating the data. I'll proceed with it.

In order to generate the resulting map, we can use *collector* [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) in conjunction with [`flatMapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) + `toList()` applied as the downstream.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
Map<String, List<? extends Employee>> dataInput = // initializing dataInput
        
Set<String> realmroles = // initializing realmroles

return Either.left().value().entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.flatMapping(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                .filter(emp -> realmroles.contains(((Employee) emp).getRole())),
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value (emp list) in your map.

```
followedResourcesServices.left().value().entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
        e.setValue(e.getValue().stream().filter(i -> realmroles.stream().anyMatch(role -> ((Employee) i).getRole().equals(role))).
                collect(Collectors.toList()));
        dataResponse.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).